# Why does backup stop at 4 gig?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup, comodo-firewall

Win 7 - 64
Comodo AV
Comodo Backup
ADATAHV420

I have a Win 7 laptop with a 500 gig HDD. I recently purchased an ADATA 2 TB HDD for backup purposes.

I downloaded Comodo Backup, installed it and attempted to backup mt C: drive.

Everything seems okay, however, at 4 gig an error message comes up, not enough room on the backup drive.

I have tried numerous times. I have whitelisted Comodo Backup.

What can I try to overcome this problem?

Comment: Make sure the 2TB drive is not fat32. 4GB is the max file size for a fat32 filesystem. Reformat it as ntfs is that is the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Windows 7 says a 8.6 GB file won't fit in 14.7 GB space?](http://superuser.com/questions/617211/windows-7-says-a-8-6-gb-file-wont-fit-in-14-7-gb-space)

Comment: @Nazard -  you were correct. It worked.