# 16Gb Extreme USB 3.0 - Unable to backup a single 10Gb vdi file on usb stick 16Gb

Tags: usb

I can't understand why I can't backup a vdi file on an 16Go USB Stick.

http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/289/~/transferring-a-4gb-or-larger-file-to-a-usb-flash-drive-or-memory-card

**does not apply.**

HOST  : Windows 10 version 1607 (14393.321)

Copy fron Host to USB Key.

**Source file :**

Size : 10,1 Go (10 865 344 512 octets)

Size on disk : 9,30 Go (9 991 163 904 octets)

compressed disk tick : ON

Format : NTFS

**Dest USB Key :**

size after format : 14.9 Go (16 008 589 312 octets)

compressed disk tick : ON

Format : NTFS

**Process stopped after more than 4Gb :**

data left :1 ( 5,3 Go)

with message : Need 5,3 Go to copy this file.

see screen copy of the message :

[image]

Seems that the usb key is not recognize as NTFS format ?

The error appear after 4GB has been copied ==> Fat32 limit !

Try with other sandisk extreme 16Gb : same error.

Any help is welcome.

My Disks are NTFS formated. In  "[Windows 7 says a 8.6 GB file won't fit in 14.7 GB space?](https://superuser.com/questions/617211/windows-7-says-a-8-6-gb-file-wont-fit-in-14-7-gb-space)"  disk are FAT32 formated and dose not apply to my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 says a 8.6 GB file won't fit in 14.7 GB space?](http://superuser.com/questions/617211/windows-7-says-a-8-6-gb-file-wont-fit-in-14-7-gb-space)

Comment: What does the "Compressed disk tick" ON mean?

Comment: I'd run a 'fake flash test' on it - see https://www.raymond.cc/blog/test-and-detect-fake-or-counterfeit-usb-flash-drives-bought-from-ebay-with-h2testw/ for suggestions on software [I'm on Mac so can't check the recommendations]

Comment: explorer.exe  select disk - properties - general tab -  at the bottom of the sub windows you find a place to select or unselect for compressing the disk.

Comment: It is not a duplicate because the disk is NTFS formated.

Comment: You will have to translate the error message into english.  Verify the flash drive isn't a fake. Why do you link to a SanDisk article about FAT32?  As a test find/locate/create a 256MB file.  Create 45 copies of this file on the drive.  If you are able to do that then the drive isn't a fake.

Comment: Run discmgmt.msc and re-format NTFS. Then use COMMAND to mv the file. Post any output errors.

Answer (score 1):

On a FAT32 drive, no single file can be larger than 4GB.
On NTFS, it's large enough for you to never worry. I believe it's either 16TB or 16EB. Can't remember.

Format your USB to NTFS

Comment: OP seems to indicate that usb drive is already formatted as NTFS.

Comment: You did not read carefully my post.