# Why can't write 4Gb file onto flash drive with 10Gb free?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb-flash-drive

Trying to write 4Gb video file onto flash drive with 10Gb free and it says

[image]

How can it be?

Flash drive is writable. Smaller files can be created / written.

Comment: so many duplicates that can be found [a 8.6 GB file won't fit in 14.7 GB space?](http://superuser.com/q/617211/241386)

Answer (score 4):

That drive is formatted as FAT32. FAT32 doesn't support file sizes over 4GB.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32

Answer (score 2):

Your Flash drive have currently the File system as FAT32.
You need to have the file system as NTFS so you can be able to copy files more than 4 Gb size.

To do this, you have two solutions :

1 - Convert it from FAT32 to NTFS by doing the following:

Go to **cmd** and type the following :

*convert G: /FS:NTFS*

G: (G is your flash drive letter as your picture shows)

(You will not loose any existing data on it when converting)

[image]

2 - Format your Flash Drive and choose NTFS as File System

(You will loose all the data on it)

[image]

[image]